# Cocoa: AVAsset from raw data (i.e. NSData)

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation, qtkit

I'd like to use **AVFoundation** to display a video on osx. I would like to initialize the movie from raw data at runtime. According to this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2300/_index.html `AVAsset` is the equivalent of **QTKit's** `QTMovie`. `QTMovie` has the function `movieWithData:error:` to load  the video from data, while i could not find anything similar in `AVAsset`. So, is it possible to do the same thing in **AVFoundation** at all?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *tempFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp.mp3"];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[manager createFileAtPath:tempFilePath contents:mp3Data attributes:nil];

AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath] options:nil];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [manager removeItemAtPath:tempFilePath error:nil];
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just shows how to write the `NSData` to a temporary file and initialize an `AVAsset` from that.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the unique possibility to initialize `AVAsset` instance from raw data is to save the data before as a file. `AVAsset` and its subclasses are using URLs only in their constructors.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create an `AVAsset` from an `NSData` via an `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` implementation.

Specifically implement:

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool
```

It must:

1. fill in the loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest correctly.  Hint, use `loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.contentType = AVFileType.mycontenttype.rawValue`
2. respond with data correctly

Comment: How to do this? How can I find your sample code? thanks.